# Dynamically generated inputs where not submitted

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which is a bunch of elements. Plus there is a Button that creates Input-Elements dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 0;

$("#addNewItem").on("click", function() {


 counter++;

    // The PHP handle to create the elements
    $.get('showItem.php?zahl=' + counter ,function(data) {

        // Add Items:
        $('#newItems').after(data);

        //Button zum erzeugen Enablen:
         $( "#btn_createItem" ).removeAttr( "disabled" );

    })

});

});
```

The PHP-handle contains this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1em;" id="item<? echo $zahl; ?>" >
<div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="taskForUser"> Product:</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="prItem<? echo $zahl; ?>" id="prItem<? echo $zahl; ?>">
                        <option selected>Please choose...</option>


                        <?  //foreach($stmtPL as $rowPL) {
                        while($rowPRL = $stmtPRL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                         // Get List from Database: ?>


                            <option><? echo $rowPRL[1] . " * " . $rowPRL[2] . " * " . $rowPRL[4]; ?></option>
                            <? } ?>

        </select>
    </div>

</div>  
<div class="col-md-3">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Count:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="anzahl<? echo $zahl; ?>" name="anzahl<? echo $zahl; ?>" value="1" maxlength="5">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

</div> <!-- /col -->

 <div class="col-md-3">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">&nbsp;</label><br />
        <a href="#newItems" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delitem" data-id="<? echo $zahl; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

    </div>

 </div><!-- /col -->
```

When I click on the button to submit the form, the dynamically generated fields are not present. I tested it with a simple: "print_r($_POST);"
Only the "hardcoded" fields are listet in the array. What can it be?

Comment: check the name of all inputboxes are generating unique in form or not??

Comment: What I can see is that the names are unique.

Comment: Is there a way to view the code that is dynamically generated?

Comment: in console..ajax request you can see html..and event after html added to you page by inspecting you can see html

Comment: I checked it. The names are unique!

Comment: Still stick into this problem. Any Ideas what it can be?